# JS/JQuery : Can not append html more than one line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a problem returning data on a div

this function don't work on files larges than more a line of code or i think maybe a string.

how can i do ?

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01" class="displayPage">Home</li>
</ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
  var menu_id = event.currentTarget.id;
  if($(this).hasClass('displayPage')) {

    getMenu(menu_id);
    event.stopPropagation(); //Stop les event JS qui suivent
  } else {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    getMenu(menu_id);
  }

});

function getMenu(menu_id) {
  console.log(menu_id);
  switch(menu_id) {
    case 'uniqueId01':
      menu1();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId02':
      menu2();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId03':
      menu3();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId04':
      menu4();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId05':
      menu5();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId06':
      menu6();
      break;
    default:
      console.log("default case");
      break;
  }
}

function menu1() {
  console.log('menu 1 ');
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( 'ok 1' );
}

function menu2() {
  console.log('menu 2 ');
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( 'ok 2' );
}

function menu3() {
  console.log('menu 3 ');
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( 'ok 3' );
}

</script>

  <div id="wrapper_page_desktop_content"></div>
```

Into this

```
$('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( 'CONTENT' );
```

i can't append more than a line of content (flat php file).

please help

I have no known of javascript, if u want i can respond you on infrastructure questions !

Benjamin

ps normally you can't display this

```
<html>

ONE LINE
</br>
TWO LINE
</html>
```

in reality i can't display a included php file at the place of text or content with more than one line of code

if i return in file php, the second line put the file non-displayed

```
function menu1() {
    console.log('menu 1 ');
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 
'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `i can't append more than a line of content (flat php file).`?

Comment: i have answered by post edit, thank u

Comment: you try to add php tag which may be interpreted server side while you(re manipulating DOM client -side

Answer (score 0):

**As JQuery API defined for** [html():](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

So the issue you met is your content was interpreted as html element and the element is not visialbe.

If you'd like to display them as plain text, you can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

**text() defined**:

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML.

This function will help you escape your content.

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01" class="displayPage">Test1 By html()</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02" class="displayPage">Test2 By text()</li>
  <li id="uniqueId03" class="displayPage">Test3 By html()</li>
</ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
  var menu_id = event.currentTarget.id;
  if($(this).hasClass('displayPage')) {

    getMenu(menu_id);
    event.stopPropagation(); //Stop les event JS qui suivent
  } else {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    getMenu(menu_id);
  }

});

function getMenu(menu_id) {
  console.log(menu_id);
  switch(menu_id) {
    case 'uniqueId01':
      menu1();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId02':
      menu2();
      break;
    case 'uniqueId03':
      menu3();
      break;
    default:
      console.log("default case");
      break;
  }
}

function menu1() {
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( 'ok 1' );
}

function menu2() {
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').text( "'<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>'" );
}

function menu3() {
  $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<p style="background:red">rendered as html element</p>' );
}

</script>

  <div id="wrapper_page_desktop_content"></div>
```

Comment: i cant display elements they stay blocked in the function when displayed

Comment: blocked? what do you mean? only display <?php ..>? If so, that is what @scraaappy explained at the comment, php tag is interpreted by the backend server, not client side. You’d better to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need escape like json_encode to assign js value from php directly.

.

```
var foo ="bar"; //valid
var foo="bar\
\
hshsj\
ghhhhhh";//valid
/*what are you doing:*/
var foo="bar

ghhsjs
ghhi";//invalid
```

2. you better using ajax if you want retrieve data from server.

here to hack your issue.

```
$('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php json_encode(file_get_contents(app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php')); ?>' );
```